# Ford Focus 2006 - Trunk latch won't close

Tags: electrical, maintenance

I lost my keys, so I had a locksmith come and make another Key. He took the lock latch off to do something with a computer as well as the door and ignition. Now the trunk latch will not latch and close. He says it is pretty worn out, but it was working properly before. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two immediate thoughts come to mind. The first being the latch is already in the closed position. Insert the key and turn it as you would normally to open the trunk. If you heard a clunk sound the latch unlocked, and the trunk may now work  again.  If nothing happened the latch may be stuck in the closed position. Looking at the latch you should see a "U" shaped opening that the striker should fit in. The second thought is that the latch is now misadjusted after it was reinstalled. If you can see the latch see if all the old paint lines match up. This can be a tricky adjustment. If the latch is in the incorrect position it may not latch or it may latch and not reopen. I would contact the Locksmith and ask if the have a Body Repair shop that they prefer. Bring it to the Body Repair shop and send the bill to the Locksmith if it turns out to be their fault.